# How to reference all cells from a cell to the very bottom and right in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, reference, range, spreadsheet, offset

I know you can reference cells in these ways:

| Address | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `A1` | The cell at `A1` |
| `A2:A` | All rows in column `A` starting from row `2` |
| `B1:1` | All columns in row `1` starting from column `B` |

What I can't find it how to reference all rows and columns starting at `B2`. Is that possible?

I am not opposed to using a formula but would prefer not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are several ways one of wich is:

```
=INDIRECT("B2:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), COLUMNS(1:1)))
```

or:

```
=OFFSET(B2,,,9^9,9^9)
```

Comment: So there is no non-formula way? Like a range reference thing?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan if you just want to preview the range try: `="B2:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), COLUMNS(1:1), 4)`

Comment: Ha. No. I actually used your solution (I went with the first one as I assume it is more efficient) but was just hoping there is a non formula way. Thanks!